# Can't load new Order attribute in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, payment

I've a module where I'm adding a new attribute to sales/order class.

```
ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/order')}` ADD `my_attribute` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'BLA BLA';
```

Looking into the database I can see this new attribute in sales/order table.

But when I load an order in the payment process with:

```
$_order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$_order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

this order is not loading the new attribute `my_attribute`. It looks `my_attribute` is created but `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` is not recognizing it.

How can I load the order with my new custom attribute?

Comment: have you assigned any value to your custom attribute ?

Comment: yep! in the database I can see a '2' value

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to below file :

**Namespace/Module/etc/config.php**

```
<global>
   ….. 
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>                           
            <my_attribute><to_order>*</to_order></my_attribute>
        </sales_convert_quote>

        <sales_convert_order>                                              
            <my_attribute><to_quote>*</to_quote></my_attribute>
        </sales_convert_order>
    </fieldsets>
    …
</global>
```

Comment: After adding this, do I need to upgrade the module version to take these changes into consideration? Thanks!

Comment: No. try without updating the version once